# Rewrite this loop function with range

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range

Is it possible to rewrite this loop:

```
for k,n in [[aa,1],[ab,2], [ac,3], [ad,4], [ba,5], [bb,6], [bc,7], [bd,8], 
            [ca,9],[cb,10],[cc,12],[cd,13],[da,14],[db,15],[dc,16],[dd,17],...zd,220]]:
```

with two range functions or "list multiplication"? I have tried all sorts of approaches, but none worked so far.

Thank you.

Comment: it is a series of matplotlib objects. each controls one subplot of the larger chart.

Comment: Unless you have all those `aa`, etc. in some kind of iterable, there is no way to make this any shorter.

Comment: See @Space_C0wb0y... are the objects in an iterable (e.g. list)? If yes, it's easy - otherwise pretty much impossible.

Comment: btw there are well under 220 elements.  26*4=104

Comment: @jon_darkstar: you are right. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the objects in a list its actually quite simple:

```
object_list = [aa, ab, ... ]
for n, k in enumerate( object_list, start=1):
     ...
```

So you should look for a way to put them in a list instead.

Answer (score 0):

If all those objects are in the modules global namespace you could do something like this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
n = 1
for a in ascii_lowercase:
    for b in ascii_lowercase[0:4]:
        k = globals()[a+b]
        n+=1
```

If they are in a function's namespace you could try `locals()` instead of `globals()`

Comment: Same as @pyfunc: What makes you think the OP wants strings?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give much information, so this might not be what you are looking for but:

```
l = [aa, ab, ... ]
for i in xrange(len(l)):
  k = l[i]
  n = i+1
  //the rest of your code
```

That being said, based on the names of your variables, it looks like you have a matrix of values. If that is the case, it would make more sense you use that kind of structure and just iterate over both indices rather than having lots of named variables.

Comment: Whenever you write `[x]range(len(...))` in Python, you either have very weird requirements, or you don't use iterators properly.

Comment: good point, it kind of screams for a 26x4 table.  I didn't consider that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have these matplotlib in an iterable, `objs`:

```
([i, obj] for i, obj in enumerate(objs, 1))
```

This can be made much shorter and simpler if you used 2-tuples instead of lists of length two (you propably want this anyway!): `enumerate(objs, 1)`.

Comment: Since he iterates over them anyway (`for k, n in ...`) you do not even have to make it a list.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Yes, thanks for the hint - turned it into a generator.

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach :

```
alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e',] # Continue to have a complete alphabet

# Generator that returns every combination of a given alphabet with a given length
def xcombinations(items, n): 
    if n==0: yield []
    else:
        for i in xrange(len(items)):
            for cc in xcombinations(items[:i]+items[i+1:],n-1):
                yield [items[i]]+cc



gen = xcombinations(alphabet, 2)

for p,k in enumerate(gen):
    print ["".join(k), p]
```

Edit :

`xcombinations` can be replaced by `itertools.permutations` who does the same things.

Comment: i see that everybody loves 'enumerate'

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase`, `itertools.permutations`. Know your standard library.

Comment: don't be so offensive. string.asccii_lowercase can't be used until we don't know the corpus that must be used for the generation of his range. Indeed, we can replace my xcombinations with itertools.permutations.

Answer (score 0):

try these.

```
[[j,i] for i,j in enumerate([c1+c2 for c1 in ascii_lowercase for c2 in ascii_lowercase[0:4]])]
```

[j,i] just for printing in the order you said.  put function or whatever you want there.
or if you prefer loop to list-comp

```
for i,j in enumerate([c1+c2 for c1 in ascii_lowercase for c2 in ascii_lowercase[0:4]]):
    #loop body
```

im guessing aa thru zd are either in global namespace or (hopefully) a dict?  just put either eval() or dict name around the c1+c2

```
for i,j in enumerate([dictname['c1+c2'] for c1 in ascii_lowercase for c2 in ascii_lowercase[0:4]]):
    #loopbody
```